# What is more accurate: an ensemble of CNN or an ensemble of weak learners with a neural network meta learner?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, ensemble-learning

Would it be better to use an ensemble of CNNs for medical images or several weak learners with a meta-learner of a neural network?

These medical images would be tissue sections or blood smears and I would want to classify the disease subtypes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is impossible to answer, you can only find out the answer with experimentation.

Comment: key question for ml and dl; hopefully someone can provide papers and proof of a better approach